# C# Найти слово

Tags: c#

Как узнать, есть ли слово "text" в переменной?

Answer (score 3):

```
string value = "my text";
if(value.Contains("text"))
{
     // Строка содержит искомую фразу.
}
```

Подробнее: [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот так:

```
private bool MethodName(string Text)
{
Regex CheckIfThere = new Regex("text");
return CheckIfThere.IsMatch(Text);
}
```

Comment: Регулярное выражение — наверное слишком сильный инструмент для такой проверки.

Comment: Зато расширяет границы познания для тех, кто учится. Не так ли? Вряд ли вопрошающий действительно ищет именно слово `text` в строке.